# I have two questions. Q1. Conditional Q2. verb agreement

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I would like to know which one of the below two sentences are right:

> If I **am** in Russia, I will get in touch with you

or

> If I **will** be in Russia, I will get in touch with you.

---

> The three best things about the NGO **was** the team, agenda, and the funding.

or

> The three best things about the NGO **were** the team, agenda, and the funding.

In the first question, the first answer seems more fitting to me.
Second sentence, should we use **were** or **was** because NGO is considered singular and the latter part of the sentence is plural as it refers three things.
I would also like to know the explanation.

Comment: Q1: *[When] I am* or *If I [visit]*; Q2: *three* ... *were*.

Comment: I note that you're asking for explanations. To help avoid wasted effort etc on the part of respondents, please [edit] your question to provide some information about what you've found or considered so far, as well as which version you think sounds better, and why.

Comment: I dont understand 1st question reply. For the second question did u mean plural 'were' because of 'the team, agenda and the funding'? @Lawrence

Comment: Presumably your first sentence refers to contacting a person who lives in Russia. It would be more natural to say 'When I am in Russia'. or 'If I go to (or visit) Russia'. Obviously a sentence about three things needs a plural verb.

Answer (score 1):

in the first two sentences **the first is the correct one**, while the second is incorrect because there is **no such if clause**, that is, no conditional that uses **the future tense** in both clauses.
in the second two sentences **the second is the correct one** because **the subject** of that sentence is *the three best things*.the verb **must agree** with that subject, so it needs to be **plural**.